# Is it possible to have a one time payment with WooCommerce Subscriptions

Tags: woocommerce

I was thinking about setting up a subscription, but I wanted to have a one time payment of the subscription, anybody know if this is possible?

For example, the subscription is $120 and good for one year.  But they pay one time (at the start) and after one year the subscription expires.  I am hoping WooCommerce subscriptions can do this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the product settings for Subscriptions? You can set the billing interval, billing period, and duration of subscription.

[image: product settings]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was looking at that, I was thinking setting it for 1-year billing interval and for 1 year.  I just want to be sure it is only billed the one time and that there will be no surprises for the customer a year later.

Comment: If 1 year is the length of the subscription, you won't be billed beyond that. You could test this out by creating a 1 day long subscription to confirm. Lastly, if this is the answer, then please accept.